# Find the maximum perimeter of a right angled triangle with hypotenuse 1

Tags: trigonometry

This is a question from the grade 7 Math Competition. I can solve it by considering one of the angles, say $\theta$, besides the right angle. We have the perimeter given by $1+\cos\theta+\sin\theta = 1+\sqrt{2}\cos(\theta-\pi/4 )$ and the rest is easy. However, I believe there should be an elementary but elegant way to solve it. Any inspiration?

Comment: Hint: $\;\frac{a+b}{2} \le \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}\,$ a.k.a. the AM-RMS (root mean square) inequality.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried to let one of the sides, say x,  besides the hypotenuse and failed. That was where I needed the AM-RMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is more elementary, but we can replace the trigonometric functions using the Pythagorean Theorem.

If one of the legs is $x$, then the remaining leg is $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. The perimeter is then
$$
1+x+\sqrt{1-x^2}\tag1
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\left(x+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2
&=1+\sqrt{4x^2-4x^4}\tag{2a}\\
&=1+\sqrt{1-\left(2x^2-1\right)^2}\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$

$\text{(2b)}$ is no more than $2$ since $\sqrt{1-\left(2x^2-1\right)^2}\le1$. $\text{(2b)}$ equals $2$ when $x=\frac1{\sqrt2}$. This means that
$$
x+\sqrt{1-x^2}\le\sqrt2\tag3
$$
and $(3)$ equals $\sqrt2$ when $x=\frac1{\sqrt2}$. Therefore,
$$
1+x+\sqrt{1-x^2}\le1+\sqrt2\tag4
$$
and $(4)$ equals $1+\sqrt2$ when $x=\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: In the spirit of my comment to Etemon’s answer, the perimeter is $1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-\left(2x^2-1\right)^2}}$, which is maximized when $2x^2-1=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume the sides of the right triangle are $a,b,1$. We have $a^2+b^2=1$ and we should find the maximum value of $a+b+1$.Hence we need to maximize  $a+b$ or $(a+b)^2$ which is equal to $a^2+b^2+2ab=1+4S$ (where $S$ is area of right triangle).
[image]

Now from the image, can you see when the area of the right triangle is maximum?

Comment: (+1) The perimeter is $1+\sqrt{1+4S}$, which is maximized when the area $S$ is. We’ve both reduced the problem to a more obvious maximization problem.

Comment: This is a very nice Geometric interpretation!

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Comment: @robjohn Yes it looks easier to use the formula, but I explained my thinking process in the answer. Sure,  one with more insight could recognize $a+b=\sqrt{(a+b)^2}=\ldots$ at first!